# jQuery on click of <a> won't run function

Tags: jquery, click, parent, siblings

I currently have an `<a>` witin an `<li>` which when clicked, opens a sub menu.

I now want to make it so that is you click that `<a>` when it's parent has a class of `.open`, it closes. But it won't fire.

**The HTML:**

```
<li class="menu-item-has-children open">
    <a href="#">emerging market</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        [sub menu stuff]
    </ul>
</li>
```

So when you click `.open a`, it should first `hide` the `sibling ul .sub-menu` and then `removeClass` `open` from the `parent`

**The jQuery**

```
jQuery(".open a").click(
    function (){
        console.log('here!'); // this never seems to fire
        jQuery(this).sibling(".sub-menu").hide();
        jQuery(this).parent().removeClass("open");
});
```

JS Fiddle showing the (working) opening function but the non-working closing function

http://jsfiddle.net/aa5brt5v/

Comment: Is your jQuery in a document.ready call or at the end of the document? It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/70jryhj1/ (BTW it's `siblings` (plural), not `sibling`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't use just simply toggle the child list?

```js
$(".menu-item-has-children").click(function() {
  $(this).find(".sub-menu").toggle();
});
```

```css
/* Default is to hide sub menu */
ul.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="menu-item-has-children"> <a href="#">emerging market</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>[sub menu stuff]</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Very elegant solution.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense, classic overthinking! The problem I am having is that the `find` seems to be targeting incorrectly. There are actually sub-sub menus. Here is a fiddle to explain: http://jsfiddle.net/aa5brt5v/3/

Comment: Are you looking for something more line this: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ct5vcohs/?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because the events are assigned on DOMReady. At that time there are no `.open` elements as you are adding that class on click of the element, which is well after DOMReady has fired. Instead you could use a single click event on the element. You also can tidy up your logic and DOM traversal a little too, try this:

```
$(".menu-item-has-children").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).removeClass("open").find(".sub-menu").hide();
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("open").find(".sub-menu").show();
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aa5brt5v/2/)

Comment: I can't seem to get this working. It no longer adds the class "open"

Answer (score 1):

Try using this (Event delegation):

```
$( ".menu-item-has-children a" ).on( "click", ".open", function() {
 console.log('here!'); 
});
```

Comment: yeash, seems you are missing event delegation, which this answer provides.

Comment: @eg_dac - Why is event delegation necessary here?

Comment: in case of element changes which .open may be changed on the fly, therefore losing the event.

Comment: Because the .open is being added dynamically

Comment: @eg_dac - ah I see, you went by the fiddle. I was only looking at the code posted in the question which doesn't match the fiddle.